# NHibernate with sqlite throws a GenericADOException "constraint failed\r\nFOREIGN KEY constraint failed" trying to save

Tags: c#, sqlite, unit-testing, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm trying to set up an in-memory sqlite database for unit testing per [Ayende's recommendation](http://ayende.com/blog/3983/nhibernate-unit-testing).  Everything is working great except one entity, UserPermission, always causes NHibernate to throw an GenericADOException "constraint failed\r\nFOREIGN KEY constraint failed"

This is a standard one-to-many relationship; each User can have zero, one or many UserPermissions.

Here are my models:

```
public class User
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<UserPermission> UserPermissions { get; set; }
}

public class UserPermission
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual int PermissionId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual Organization Organization { get; set; }
}
```

Here are the mappings:

```
public class UserMap : ClassMap<User>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        Table("USERS");
        Id(x => x.Id).Column("USER_ID").GeneratedBy.Native(x => x.AddParam("sequence", "SEQ_USERS"));
        HasMany(x => x.UserPermissions);
        Map(x => x.LastName);
        Map(x => x.FirstName);
    }
}

public class UserPermissionMap : ClassMap<UserPermission>{
    public UserPermissionMap()
    {
        Table("USER_PERMISSION");
        Id(x => x.Id).Column("USER_PERMISSION_ID").GeneratedBy.Native(x => x.AddParam("sequence", "SEQ_USER_PERMISSION")); 
        Map(x => x.PermissionId);
        References(x => x.User).Column("USER_ID");
        References(x => x.Organization).Column("ORG_ID").Nullable();
    }
}
```

I have googled around quite a bit this afternoon and came across a few seemingly relevant posts but none of their suggestions worked for me.  Specifically here is what I tried:

- In UserMap I tried adding Inverse() to the HasMany(x => x.UserPermissions)
- Also in UserMap I tried adding Cascade.All() to the HasMany(x => x.UserPermissions)
- In UserPermissionMap I tried adding Cascade.All() to References(x => x.User)
- Various combinations of the above
- In my tests the Organization is always null but I have tried setting it to a dummy Organization and that did not fix it

The crazy thing is that I am able to create and save UserPermission objects against an Oracle database; this error only happens when I attempt to save a UserPermission against sqlite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it figured out.  We have a Permission model that had a HasMany mapped to UserPermission, but the UserPermission does not have a References to the Permission model.  At one point the UserPermission model probably had a Permission property that would return the Permission object, then we changed it to an int and forgot to update the Permission mapping.

Here is what I found in my PermissionMap:

```
public class PermissionMap : ClassMap<Permission>
{
    public PermissionMap()
    {
        Table("PERMISSION");
        Id(x => x.Id).Column("PERMISSION_ID");
        Map(x => x.Name);
        HasMany(x => x.UserPermissions).LazyLoad();  // Removed this line to fix issue
    }
}
```

**Lesson learned:** when you remove a relationship between to models, don't forget to remove it from BOTH sides.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to define your `HasMany` mapping as :

```
HasMany(x => x.UserPermissions)
  .KeyColumn("User_ID")
  .Cascade
  .AllDeleteOrphan()
  .Inverse();
```

The .`AllDeleteOrphan` would delete a `UserPermission` as part of its removal from the `UserPermissions` list. 
You may replace it with a simple `.All` if it is not the desired behavior.

Comment: That didn't fix it. :(  I tried what you posted as well as Cascade.All(), Cascade.All().Inverse(), and just Inverse().